# AngularJS directive which adds class, I'm confused

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Let's consider example:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': (form.title.$dirty && form.title.$invalid) }">
   <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input ng-model="vm.item.name" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" ng-required="true" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I have several input fields and this `ng-class="{'has-error': (form.title.$dirty && form.title.$invalid) }"` looks dirty for me.

I'm trying to create directive which encapsulates it to `has-error`, so it will look like:

```
<form name="form" has-error=".form-group">
...
</form>

   // ddo for it.
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "form",
        link: function(scope, elements, attributes, form) {
            var selector = attributes["hasError"];
            // 1. find all controls with ng-models
            // 2. validate it
            // 3. find closest element by matched selector and add class `has-error`
        }
    };
};
```

`.form-group` is selector for closest parent container of input with ng-model.

So the question is how to implement steps 1-3 in proper angulary way?

Comment: Why do you think ng-class is dirty?

Comment: You can use `ng-form`. It can be nested within real form. It will automatically validate contents and assign classes such as `ng-dirty`, `ng-invalid` etc.

Comment: You can create a directive like tag-error-for="field" and then, find closest form name, and use $scope[formName][field].$invalid. I liked your think.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just use Angular ng-invalid and ng-dirty CSS classes? They are automatically assigned to specific input with ng-model and if you need custom validation check out this docs:

[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Simple Example:

HTML

```
<form novalidate>
  <input type='text' ng-model='vm.item.name' required>
</form>
```

CSS

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yiPxeq30cLSZ83nrqUNn?p=preview)

Comment: Because he/she pretends to mark a border around a getbootstrap component, not only at input component.

Comment: But still Angular also appends those classes to form itself and if element is inside form you can just use css inheritance to achieve desired effect. Checkout my edited plunkr

Comment: But the inherited form style would apply to all sub elements (e.g. all spans in your plunkr) not just the specific group of sub elements where the input error is caused.